# Can we use Cloud SQL federated queries to insert data from BigQuery to Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Can we use Cloud SQL federated queries to insert data from BigQuery to Cloud SQL

Answer (score 4):

Federated queries enables BigQuery to query data residing in Cloud SQL in real-time and introduces a new function: EXTERNAL_QUERY. Unfortunately, as per official documentation there are some limitations and one of them [“The external query that will be executed in the source database must be read-only.“](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#external_querying_is_read-only), means that you can’t use federated queries to insert data to Cloud SQL.